# SQL conceptional: how many ways to "add" column and row to a result set?

Tags: sql, database

I'm currently learning SQL.

SQL (with it's clause ) is mainly used for "cutting" column and row from the result set to get the desired data.

It seems, there is only two ways to "add" columns:

```
1. join table.
2. select "virtual" column in select list.
```

And only one way we can "add" rows:

```
1. union
```

How many other ways can you think out?

Comment: If you can give a scenario it would help us to understand better :)

Comment: Because this is not about a particular database I removed the Oracle and MySQL tags.  Use the tags when you have a question about a particular database.  "sql" is appropriate for a generic SQL question.

Comment: this question seems pretty broad, but when you see it like this you can also `add rows to a result set if you use a less restrictive where clause` ;)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste ... just conceptional :) where mainly for cut rows, is it?

Comment: @lovespring exactly, where restricts your result set to the rows that meet the criteria in your where-clause

Comment: @DrCopyPaste so, I' want to know the "add", just conceptional "add"

Comment: @lovespring `join`s do not really add columns to your result set, you always do that yourself, the `join` however CAN add columns to your result set IMPLICITLY if you `SELECT *` or `SELECT alias.* `, that aside the only way to add columns to your result set is by selecting them explicitly

Comment: @Luv How can you make it syntax highlight?

Comment: `Join` can add row, if it's an Outer Join (`LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `FULL`)

Answer (score 1):

You can add any number of columns like

```
select 111 as col1, now() as col2 ... from
```

etc.

Rows could be added by CROSS JOINS new tables or just include tables or subselects in the FROM

```
select *
from table1, (select 1
             union
             select 2) as row2
```

The second select row2 doubles rows in table1

Answer (score 1):

There are a few inaccuracies in your question. Lets deal with them first. You are dealing with sets of records. If you think about a set of records as a spreadsheet of data you won't go far wrong.

Adding columns, you are simply adding a new heading to your spreadsheet.

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM myTable
```

If you want to select all available columns you might say:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
```

A Union statement is taking two separate sets of records and combining them together into a single one.  Thinking about it from our spreadsheet perspective, it's like copying and pasting rows out of one sheet into another. The columns have to line up, otherwise the resulting table will be a bit weird!

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM myTable

UNION

SELECT col3, col4
FROM myOtherTable
```

A "Join" is another way of joining two tables together but this time relating them to each other. You would normally join them on a Primary Key on one table to a Foreign key of another to ensure they relate to each other. Once joined, the SELECT clause can then access the columns from the other table.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM myTable
INNER JOIN myOtherTable on myTable.col1 = myOtherTable.col2
```

If we wanted to get all columns from the above example we could again use a * in the select clause.

So to get back to your original question, "are there other ways"... Different databases have different commands but they generally revolve around the same common SQL syntax. As an example Microsoft SQL Server allows you to execute dynamic SQL statements effectively building up your select statement before you run it (in other words you could create dynamic list of columns if you wanted to). You can also PIVOT data converting rows to columns or visa versa.

Have a read about some basic SQL to get you in the picture. [Here is a good start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)